# HttpPost does not get ContentLength from PostAsync request

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, .net-core

I have a unit test code that sends request to an HttpPost method.

```
[Test]
public async Task ValidateToken()
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string("test", "test")
    };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/api/token/1", content);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, response.StatusCode);
}

[Route("api/token")]
public class MyController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly HttpRequest httpRequest;
    public MyController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        httpRequest = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
    }

    [HttpPost("{count}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(int count)
    {
        if(httpRequest.ContentLength)
            return BadRequest();
        else
            return Accepted();

        var success= await store.SaveLogStreamAsync(httpRequest.Body, count);
        return success ? Accepted() : InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

This unit test always fails because `httpRequest.ContentLength` is null. However, when I put a breakpoint on this line and check the `ContentLength` of `content`, it is always greater than 0.

`var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/api/token/1", content);`

Also, when I put a breakpoint before it reaches the Action method, the ContentLength is not 0 anymore. I'm thinking, is there some delay when sending the content?

**EDIT:**

What I found out is that when testing this from a unit test, the `httpRequest.Body` is of type `MemoryStream` and `httpRequest.ContentLength = null`

When the request is sent from Postman, the `httpRequest.Body` is of type `FrameRequestStream` and `httpRequest.ContentLength` always has a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the request by doing this:

```
  var length= Request.Content.Headers.ContentLength ;
```

Dunno from where `httpRequest` variable is coming

Comment: I added the code to see where httpRequest came from